# getting the number of users in localytics (new,total, returning) on the basis of dialy , weekly, monthly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I need to get the number of users (total, new,returning) of localytics(with days). I'm doing an app where I login to localytics with my credentials, once i click  login it should authenticate  and after authenticating  when i click on the user tab , i need to print  the number of users  who are using particular app(localytics).

```
NSString *accept = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.abc.com"];          
NSLog(@"accept %@",accept);     NSString *authHeader = [@"Basic " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", loginString];     
NSLog(@"auth header =%@",authHeader);          
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url                                                            cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData                                                        timeoutInterval: 3];     NSLog(@"request %@",request);          
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];     
[request setValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];         
[request addValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
```

This is what I have done to get the no of users of localytics , but 'm not getting the proper response . Please do help me with this